# Convert ARC BIL to netCDF

Tags: convert, netcdf, band-interleaved-by-line

We are interested in using a dataset created by a fire lab. The data is in ARC BIL format. Is there a way to convert this into netCDF?

Answer (score 2):

You might try the [Raster to netCDF](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Raster_to_NetCDF/004300000008000000/) tool in ArcView.

Answer (score 2):

GDAL supports both netCDF and BIL (according to: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html). If you are looking for an open source solution, this seems to be a good way to go.

Note though that NetCDF support in GDAL is optional, and not compiled in by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in R:

```r
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)

setwd("path of your data folder")
f<-list.files(pattern = ".bil")

for (i in 1:length(f)){
  rd<-raster(f[i]) # read your bil files
  name_nc<-tools::file_path_sans_ext(f[i])
  rnc <- writeRaster(rd, filename=paste(name_nc,".nc",sep=""), format="CDF", overwrite=TRUE)
}
```